# Can I redirect to another JSP after a POST?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/trip")
public class BusController {

private BusDao bdao;

@Inject
public BusController(BusDao bdao) {
    this.bdao = bdao;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String create(@ModelAttribute Bus bus) {


    return "redirect:/ordersummary";

}
```

After the create runs, im trying to redirect to another JSP named "ordersummary.jsp" I cant seem to figure out how to do it. Do I need another controller with a get that redirects there?

Comment: Yes you need either another controller or another method with requestmapping /ordersummary.

Answer (score 0):

The your code is correct, however when you perform a redirect you need of configure a controller that handled the get request that the redirect will perform.

For this reason your controller could be as below:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/trip")
public class BusController {

private BusDao bdao;

@Inject
public BusController(BusDao bdao) {
    this.bdao = bdao;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String create(@ModelAttribute Bus bus) {


    return "redirect:/ordersummary";

}

@RequestMapping(value = "/ordersummary", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String redirectHAndler(....) {

...
    return "yourView";
}

}
```

I hope that it can help you